# React ExoticComponent cannot be called

Tags: reactjs, typescript

While diving on React.Fragment, I encountered a strange Intellisense message on VisualStudio Code:

> NOTE: Exotic component cannot be called.

While researching I found out something related to "Exotic component" but no tips on what actually it.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts

Can someone please explain me why this happens and what is an ExoticComponent?

This is a block of code where the message appeared in the blink of an eye:

```
// ...

render () {
    return (
        <RandomComponent
            tabs={[
                {
                    label: (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            Confirm ordered qty
                            <WarningIcon />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                    parentClasses: {
                        labelContainer: classes.tabContainer,
                        label: classes.tab,
                    },
                }, {
                    label: (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            Material to be approved
                            <WarningIcon />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                    disabled: !IsMaterialToBeAnalyzed,//SystemTypeCode !== 'PALETTI',
                    parentClasses: {
                        labelContainer: classes.tabContainer,
                        label: classes.tab,
                    },
                },
                {
                    label: (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            Assign materials to staging area
                            <WarningIcon />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                    parentClasses: {
                        labelContainer: classes.tabContainer,
                        label: classes.tab,
                    },
                }
            ]}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `React.Fragment` type is declared using the `ExoticComponent` interface ([Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/dc09e01c627597d4b412f03b1aa126dab3fa0049/types/react/index.d.ts#L346))

```
const Fragment: ExoticComponent<{ children?: ReactNode }>;
```

From a comment next to [`ExoticComponent` type declaration](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/dc09e01c627597d4b412f03b1aa126dab3fa0049/types/react/index.d.ts#L306-L311)

> However, we have no way of telling the JSX parser that it's a JSX element type or its props other than by pretending to be a normal component.
>
> We don't just use ComponentType or SFC types because you are not supposed to attach statics to this object, but rather to the original function.

The `ExoticComponent` a workaround for typing special components (hence the name "exotic"), which do not behave as regular `React.Component` or `React.FunctionComponent`, but we still want TypeScript to interpret them as a kind of component.

---

Regarding the message you're seeing:

> NOTE: Exotic component cannot be called.

This might be an interface or a plugin glitch. There's nothing wrong with your code.